# IIS not returning HTTP/304 on conditional request made with If-None-Match

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, fiddler

I have made a request for a video which returns a video with an ETAG.

When I make a request for the same video again, I can see the If-non-match header passed from the browser with the Etag but instead of 304 returned, the video is downloaded again with a 200 OK response.

In fiddler for the very first request for the video, the response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: max-age=10
Content-Length: 76278442
Content-Type: video/mp4
Last-Modified: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 08:47:29 GMT
ETag: "2117329216"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Mod-H264-Streaming: version=2.2.7
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 23 Aug 2013 21:20:34 GMT
```

On the second request, the GET headers are:

```
GET http://test/video.mp4 HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-GB
x-flash-version: 11,8,800,94
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
If-Modified-Since: Wed, 21 Aug 2013 08:47:29 GMT
If-None-Match: "2117329216"
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

But in this case, I get the whole video downloaded rather than a 304 non modified response.

I noticed that X-Mod-H264-Streaming was used, not sure if this may have something to do with it.

**Edit**

I used the URL to the video in IE 10 directly (not using the flex application we were using before) and I get the same response where on the first request I get the complete video and after hitting f5 I get the whole video returned again rather than a 304 response.

Comment: What is your code doing? IIRC, it should be checking for the existence of the If-None-Match header and checking the ETag against the one fiddler is sending up.

Comment: Is there some reason that you're sending max-age=10 on the initial response?

Comment: @EricLaw : No, I just thought a combination might help. If I remove it, I get the same problem where the whole resource is returned.

Comment: @DavidN : This is a static resource (returning a video, although it uses the Mod-h264 streaming module). I do not have any code that I have written which does any checking. I thought IIS would handle this by itself for a static resource?

Comment: Any ideas? This could be a show stopper if we don't resolve.

Comment: one option is to first do a HEAD request (not a GET), and compare the ETag it sends back with the one you would be sending with the GET/If-None-Match request, and just not go ahead if the ETag matches. sure it splits it into 2 requests, but for large files this is a non issue.

Comment: @JD. I am facing the same issue. Were you able to resolve this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think in my case it has something to do with X-Mod-H264 streaming module. I sent an email to them, but no reply.